# Одна сущность для работы с базой и JSON

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Разрабатываю Rest Api на Spring . Проект растет в размерах. И начинают возникать вопросы. Раньше entity использовались для работы с бд и JSON.
Но теперь там куча аннотаций @JsonIgnore, @Transiet и т.д. Возникла мысль разделить это все по разным сущностям. Но теперь будет куча схожих, между собой классов. Например Entity `User`, с полями: `id`, `name`, `login`, `password`, `role`., `UserResponse` для формирования JSON  с полями: `id`, `name`, `role`. Как лучше всего это сделать? Использовать DTO или разделить на модули. Модуль для работы с бд. Модуль внешних интерфейсов(JSON). Модуль для бизнес логики и т.д

Comment: По сути Ваш JSON в REST - это View. Ограничьтесь получением нужных данных из БД, а уже на слое View проводите трансформацию. Схожие классы это нормально, так и должно быть в части DDD (разложение по контекстам), каждый класс отвечает за свою обязанность и изменение одного класса не затронет другой, как к примеру с аннотацией @JsonIgnore. По-хорошему, объект из БД тоже убрать как Domain object, а выделить свой объект и наполнять его из объекта БД.

Comment: @ezhov_da ,  Спасибо за ответ. Но немного не понял это "По-хорошему, объект из БД тоже убрать как Domain object, а выделить свой объект и наполнять его из объекта БД." Можете подробнее описать?

Comment: Дополнил и перенес в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути Ваш JSON в REST - это View.
Ограничьтесь получением нужных данных из БД, а уже на слое View проводите трансформацию.
Схожие классы это нормально, так и должно быть в части DDD (разложение по контекстам), каждый класс отвечает за свою обязанность и изменение одного класса не затронет другой, как к примеру с аннотацией @JsonIgnore.
По-хорошему, объект из БД тоже убрать как Domain object, а выделить свой объект и наполнять его из объекта БД.

На данный момент У Вас с изменениями появится 2 объекта JsonUser и DbUser. 
JsonUser - это View, DbUser - персистентный объект для хранения в БД. Можно сделать еще один объект User, который будет Вашей моделью, так сказать смысловым объектом ядра приложения.

Как с ним работать:
Получаете DbUser и инстанцируете из него User.
Важно! Вы сами отвечаете за то как строится объект User, а не JPA. К примеру, если User будет иметь данные получаемые из сокета или URL, можно смело добавить этот функционал, а не добавлять в объект DbUser это поле и аннотацию игнорирования.

Таким образом Ваш объект User ни как не зависит от используемого Вами фрэймворка JPA.